# Would it be possible to design a SoC have to two antenna?

Tags: rf, analog, antenna, digital-communications, soc

If you use an actual SoC such as the Qualcomm Snapdragon Processor for mobile communications would it be possible to have two cores both sharing a common IO (Cellular/WiFi/GPS/Bluetooth) integrated circuits but its own separate antenna ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that's default. All cores share resources (IO being one of them). Each of the cores wouldn't have their own antenna though, no. Wifi/Cell/GPS/Bluetooth may have their own antenna though. There's no point in duplicate antenna for two different applications because one would cause so much noise on the other one that you'd never be able to receive anything besides what the other antenna is broadcasting.

Instead, the standard way to do multiple things on an antenna is to do TDM ([Time division multiplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-division_multiplexing)).

Comment: Hello hota and Simon. Thank you both for the responses. Horta one question to ask. Is it possible even in just theory to have two antennas one for one core and another antenna for a secondary core ? Does the location of the core on die play a factor ? So if one of the cores is located somewhere other than on the top most layer can a baseband processor and lna, modulator oscillator and amplifier be embedded on this layer ?

Comment: @VictorM As I stated in the answer, if you have another broadcasting antenna working in the same frequency range, the two will clobber each other. From any sort of distance from the device, the receiver will see two sinusoidal waves added together. At the worst, a phase offset of 180 degrees will result in absolutely nothing being seen at the receiver because the two antenna just cancelled each other out. Can I ask what your application is and why TDM won't work for you?

Comment: @VictorM Even if you have them in phase with 0 degree offset, they'll be adding together and if one sends a 0 and the other sends a 1, the receiver won't be able to tell which antenna sent the 0 and which sent the 1.

Comment: Thank you @Horta for the above response. Would you please use your expertise describe whether two antennas could exist if the frequencies ranges used by each antenna are not of the same range ? Would it be possible to embed the second transceiver IC (baseband IC) on a separate layer other than where the primary transceiver IC (baseband processor) is located on die ? Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you again @Horta. With respect to the last question you had asked about the application. What I can tell you is that the details which I am asking is for strictly research and hypothetical purposes. At the moment there is no plans for any such a design. I wish I could reply with regards to the TDM term you have used above but I am in process of understanding what exactly this term applies to and its meaning for a layman like myself.

Comment: @VictorM Yes, if the frequency ranges are different, then the antennas and tranceiver would filter out their own signal and there would be no issue. It may be possible to use one antenna even then though and then just use filtering to receive the two different signals. I don't understand your question about embedding. You can embed the antenna if you're using traces as antenna's. Embedding IC's is not common and although I'm sure possible, not very cost effective or feasible. I don't understand the point of embedding it from an electrical standpoint.

Comment: @VictorM To your last question, for a layman, TDM is actually super duper simple. It's nothing more than arbitration for a resource. In other words, agent0 uses the resource for 1 unit of time and then agent1 gets the resource for 1 unit of time. Then it just keeps ping ponging back and forth. In this way, two different agents can share a single antenna/transceiver.

Comment: Thank you @Horta for above responses. The explanation of TDM is well done thank you. I would like to ask for some clarification of one point. Above you had said " if the frequency ranges are different, then the antennas and tranceiver would filter out their own signal and there would be no issue" yes ? Are you saying that each antenna would have its own transceiver and could both antennas (operating on different frequencies) share the same transceiver (integrated modem) ? Thank you

Comment: @VictorM The smallest amount of hardware if you don't want to do TDM would be one antenna receiving two different frequency signals which would require two different front-ends attached to the antenna. I would call the two different front-ends two different tranceivers. The reason you need two different front-ends is because the first step would be to filter for the frequency band each is interested in. If you don't have a front-end filter, you'll just get a garbled mess. The other issue here is if you use one antenna for 2 different frequencies, then it's likely not optimized for either.

Comment: @VictorM Having the antenna not optimized for either means more loss which means you have to drive more power and received signal will be weaker. So really, from a decent design perspective, you would want 2 separate antenna, 2 separate front-ends and therefore 2 separate tranceivers. And to make the design even better, you would eliminate all that extra hardware, use one, and use TDM which is "just software". If you're requiring low-latency on each, just make sure your transmission speed is faster.

Comment: Many thanks again @Horta. One more question please. Where on the die would a RF circuit designer have to locate the front-end filter (FEF) using the Qualcomm Snapdragon 400 SoC with an integrated modem as the application ? Can the antenna port and the FEF (all parts of the baseband/transceiver IC) be located anywhere (or must it be located on the topmost layer) on the die of the Qualcomm Snapdragon 400 SoC with integrated modem ?

Comment: @VictorM I don't think you understand how silicon dies are setup. There is only **one** active layer in most integrated circuits. There's 7-16 layers of metal wires, but there's only one layer of transistors. A wise circuit designer would place it near the edge of the die so that there's the shortest possible distance to the antenna trace. It's only in 2.5D or 3D integrated circuits where you'll have multiple layers in the die: http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1279540
SnapDragon looks like a 2D chip: https://www.qualcomm.com/documents/snapdragon-400-processor-product-brief

Comment: Thank you again @Horta. Would you than be implying that the Qualcomm Snapdragon 400 Processor SoC die has only one layer of transistors which is used to represent the design structures of the multi core, dsp, gpu, modem and so on ? I thought that these design structures span multiple layers with each layer interconnected to the one above and the one below ? The 7-16 additional layers represent just bond wires which lead to the respective pins ? Thank you for the links.

Comment: @VictorM Yes, I'm 90% certain that the Snapdragon 400 has only one layer of transistors. I also was looking up some more about the metal layers and I got it wrong. There's more like 3-7 layers of wires on top of the transistors. It gets hard to keep the entire structure plane the more layers you go. The 7-16 layers I was recalling earlier is from PCB layers, which is a totally different beast. Bond wires to the package are only from the top metal layer. If that chip used multiple layers of transistors, you can bet they'd advertise it as a 2.5 or 3D chip.

Comment: Thanks @Horta. OK let's put aside the Qualcomm 400 for the moment and choose  the 810/820 Snapdragon. Now these two latest IC's should have multiple layers of transistors (5-10 perhaps representing the multi core, dsp, modem, gpu etc. Now is it possible to have two transceivers (2 x baseband IC's) along two antenna's and having each transceiver operating at different range of frequencies ? If yes then is it possible to embed the second transceiver on the bottom most layer and the first one is located on the top most layer of any recent model Snapdragon 810/820 SoC IC ?

Comment: @VictorM 810/820 is still single active layer IC. I don't understand this question. If the two different frequencies are used, you can put the two trancievers on the same layer no prob. If you can do it in one layer, why would you try and use 2? And nobody does 5-10 active layers at this time. Are you trying to build an IC? Are you trying to surgically modify an IC by adding layers to it? Without background, this question confuses me greatly.

Comment: Thanks a million @Horta. I see that you have an email address on your profile page. Would it be appropriate to carry this topic over email ?

Comment: @VictorM For sure.

Comment: There is always and only ever one layer of transistors. ICs with multiple antennas are not uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

RF protocols using the same frequency will interfere heavily, regardless of the number of antennas, so the best thing you can do is implement them in the same place and try to coordinate the services, for example by delaying outgoing Bluetooth frames while a WiFi packet is being received, because starting a transmission would interrupt the active transfer, and probably not manage to send out a packet undisturbed.

For protocols on different frequencies, you can use analog bandpass filters to isolate the different transceivers. Whether you use the same, or different antennas does not matter that much then -- the antenna geometry must match any frequency range you plan to use.

In order to reach different frequency bands at the same time, you need multiple transceivers anyway -- while it is possible to build a wideband transceiver, this is ridiculously expensive and gives worse performance, so it is uninteresting both from an economic and an engineering point of view.